# PHP Simple HTML DOM lookup

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have been playing around with the PHP simple HTML DOM parser most of the day successfully. I now want to scrape text from a page which does not have clear identifiers down to the lowest level.

I managed to bring it down to:

```
</pre><pre> </pre><p><strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v</strong><strong>an Bistro Puur</strong></p> <p><strong>Voor de vaste lage prijs van&nbsp;slechts &euro; 8,50 !</strong></p> <p>geserveerd tussen 17:00 uur &amp; 18:30 uur</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <h2>    <strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen voor week 32 zijn:</strong></h2> <p><strong><u>Dinsdag 22 Augustus:</u></strong></p> <p><strong>Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Woensdag 23 Augustus:</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>​Gekonfijte scharrelhoen bout met truffelsaus</strong></p> <p>   <strong><u>Donderdag 24 Augustus:&nbsp;</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />  <strong>Gebakken zalmfilet met witte wijnsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Vrijdag 25 Augustus;</u></strong></p> <p><strong>​In de oven gebakken kabeljauw filet met pesto saus</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Alle heerlijke Pure Daghappen worden vergezeld door een aardappelgarnituur en een frisse salade.<br />    Daghap is exclusief bijpassende wijn.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>Wij verwelkomen u graag!</strong></p> <p><em><strong>Team Bistro Puur</strong></em></p> <p class="rteindent1 rtecenter"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> an Bistro Puur
```

by using

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.bistropuur.nl/pure-daghappen');
foreach($html->find('div[class=node-content]') as $e){
    $temp = [$e->innertext];
}
```

I subsequently want to create an array that contains all the different pieces of text to allow further manipulation towards something like:

```
$data = array[Dinsdag 22 Augustus, Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus, ....].
```

I tried the following:

```
$html = '</pre><pre> </pre><p><strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v</strong><strong>an Bistro Puur</strong></p> <p><strong>Voor de vaste lage prijs van&nbsp;slechts &euro; 8,50 !</strong></p> <p>geserveerd tussen 17:00 uur &amp; 18:30 uur</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <h2>    <strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen voor week 32 zijn:</strong></h2> <p><strong><u>Dinsdag 22 Augustus:</u></strong></p> <p><strong>Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Woensdag 23 Augustus:</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>​Gekonfijte scharrelhoen bout met truffelsaus</strong></p> <p>   <strong><u>Donderdag 24 Augustus:&nbsp;</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />  <strong>Gebakken zalmfilet met witte wijnsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Vrijdag 25 Augustus;</u></strong></p> <p><strong>​In de oven gebakken kabeljauw filet met pesto saus</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Alle heerlijke Pure Daghappen worden vergezeld door een aardappelgarnituur en een frisse salade.<br />    Daghap is exclusief bijpassende wijn.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>Wij verwelkomen u graag!</strong></p> <p><em><strong>Team Bistro Puur</strong></em></p> <p class="rteindent1 rtecenter"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> an Bistro Puur';
$html = str_get_html($html); // create a html DOM object again
foreach($html->find('strong') as $e){ // search for <strong> tag
$temp[] = [$e->innertext]; // get the inside of the html tag
}
print_r($temp);

Array
(
    [0] => <pre> </pre><p><strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v</strong><strong>an Bistro Puur</strong></p> <p><strong>Voor de vaste lage prijs van&nbsp;slechts &euro; 8,50 !</strong></p> <p>geserveerd tussen 17:00 uur &amp; 18:30 uur</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <h2>   <strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen voor week 32 zijn:</strong></h2> <p><strong><u>Dinsdag 22 Augustus:</u></strong></p> <p><strong>Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Woensdag 23 Augustus:</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>​Gekonfijte scharrelhoen bout met truffelsaus</strong></p> <p>   <strong><u>Donderdag 24 Augustus:&nbsp;</u></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />  <strong>Gebakken zalmfilet met witte wijnsaus</strong></p> <p>  <strong><u>Vrijdag 25 Augustus;</u></strong></p> <p><strong>​In de oven gebakken kabeljauw filet met pesto saus</strong></p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Alle heerlijke Pure Daghappen worden vergezeld door een aardappelgarnituur en een frisse salade.<br />    Daghap is exclusief bijpassende wijn.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>Wij verwelkomen u graag!</strong></p> <p><em><strong>Team Bistro Puur</strong></em></p> <p class="rteindent1 rtecenter"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => an Bistro Puur
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Voor de vaste lage prijs van&nbsp;slechts &euro; 8,50 !
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => De heerlijke Pure Daghappen voor week 32 zijn:
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => <u>Dinsdag 22 Augustus:</u>
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => <u>Woensdag 23 Augustus:</u>
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => ​Gekonfijte scharrelhoen bout met truffelsaus
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => <u>Donderdag 24 Augustus:&nbsp;</u>
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gebakken zalmfilet met witte wijnsaus
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => <u>Vrijdag 25 Augustus;</u>
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => ​In de oven gebakken kabeljauw filet met pesto saus
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wij verwelkomen u graag!
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Team Bistro Puur
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => &nbsp;
        )

)
```

Questions:

- Why am I getting the whole html string again at `array[0]`?
- How can I quickly remove the remaining ,`<u>..</ul>` tags?
- I am obtaining 15 nested arrays. I can work with those but is it possible to remove the nesting from the start?
- Can I do all this in a more efficient way?

---

I updated to code to (based on the feedback from Peter):

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('strong') as $e){
    $temp[] = $e->plaintext;
}
```

This gives me the correct plain array with all the data. Great!

Comment: Hi! I processed your feedback and updated my code to:

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting the whole html string again at array[0]?

Probably because you still have the following line in your code, initializing the `$temp`-variable with an array with a single element `$e->innertext`.

```
$temp = [$e->innertext];
```

Initialize the `$temp` variable just before your `foreach` with `$temp = [];`.

> How can I quickly remove the remaining ,.. tags?

Use `$e->plaintext` instead of `$e->innertext` (make sure to read the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm))

> I am obtaining 15 nested arrays. I can work with those but is it possible to remove the nesting from the start?

Because you tell it to create an array everytime (why are you doing that??):

```
$temp[] = [ $e->innertext ];
          ^ array open    ^ array-close
```

Use `$temp[] = $e->innertext;` instead (or `plaintext` according to previous)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you are including html DOM, but using this script:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = '</pre><pre> </pre><p><strong>De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v</strong><strong>an Bistro Puur<$
$html = str_get_html($html); // create a html DOM object again
foreach($html->find('strong') as $e){ // search for <strong> tag
$temp[] = $e->plaintext; // get the inside of the html tag
}
var_dump_pre($temp);


function var_dump_pre($mixed = null) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($mixed);
  echo '</pre>';
  return null;
}
?>
```

...will produce this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => De heerlijke Pure Daghappen v
    [1] => an Bistro Puur
    [2] => Voor de vaste lage prijs van slechts € 8,50 !
    [3] => De heerlijke Pure Daghappen voor week 32 zijn:
    [4] => Dinsdag 22 Augustus:
    [5] => Gegrilde vakenshaas medaillons met champignonsaus
    [6] => Woensdag 23 Augustus:
    [7] => ​Gekonfijte scharrelhoen bout met truffelsaus
    [8] => Donderdag 24 Augustus: 
    [9] => Gebakken zalmfilet met witte wijnsaus
    [10] => Vrijdag 25 Augustus;
    [11] => ​In de oven gebakken kabeljauw filet met pesto saus
    [12] => Wij verwelkomen u graag!
    [13] => Team Bistro Puur
    [14] =>  
)
```